# What does mean this? take off things

Tags: american-english

Does anyone know what does this means?

Being here helps take my mind off things.

Also, What does purpose "being" as grammartically at here?

Comment: http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/take+mind+off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Take one's mind off* means to stop thinking about something, or to relax.

*Take one's mind off things* means to relax, or stop working for awhile.

If you want to use a verb as a noun, two options are the infinitive (*to be*) or the "-ing" form (*being*).

If you are talking about an action that you are doing now, and you want to turn that into a noun, and you aren't using a clause with a word like "that", etc., the "-ing" form is typically used.

> Being here helps take my mind off things

You are saying that fact that you are currently being here helps take your mind off off things.

> Being here helps me take my mind off things

is a bit more clear.